# Google App Script UrlFetchApp frequent "address unavailable" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using UrlFetchApp for API requests.

```
     var url = "https://api.bol.com/catalog/v4/search/?....
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

I need to make 1 API request for each item (unfortunately no way around that).

With few items I don't seem to have a problem. When I have over 20 items I often get an "address unavailable" error.

I only have this issue when using Google Spreadsheets, so I'm quite sure the problem lies there. From my server I can do hundreds of requests in a row without issue.

I've tried putting in a delay with using Utilities.sleep to slow down the request rate. That doesn't seem to be the issue.

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: When you run locally, can you trace any cookies/headers that are getting sent?  Perhaps you need to add an additional header with our request.

Comment: Perhaps those urls don't want you to access them any further and they blocked all of the google ips.  Also most browsers have a limit on how many responses can be pending at any given time.  I think the default limit on chrome is 6.

Comment: @Cooper It might have to the something the default limit you mentioned. I increased the delay in requests to 500ms (using Utilities.sleep) which seems to help. Obviously this increases the total running time of the script. 
Is there a way to simply have the script hold off on making the next iteration until the previous one has been processed?